# Does Dojo AMD loader ensure modules are executed only once?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

In some existing Dojo-based app I am seeing a module using a singleton pattern of the form:

```
define([...], function(...) {
  var MyClass = declare(...);
  if (!_instance) {
    var _instance = new MyClass();
  }
  return _instance;
});
```

But if I understand AMD correctly, the usage of _instance is not required, because the function passed to the define(...) call should be executed only once... or maybe not?

My understanding of the AMD loader is that when getting a module by calling "require" or "define", it will check whether the module has already been loaded. If it has not been loaded yet, it will load the JS, execute the function passed to "define", and internally store the returned value. If it has already been loaded, it will simply return the previously-stored value.

Are my assumptions correct? If so, when writing a module, we can safely assume that a given module will only be loaded and executed once, and we don't need to perform any check to see whether something has already been initialized or not, making the code simpler.

Thank you.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, that code assumes the body might be run again, which is totally false. Can I ask where you saw this, if it was in dojo/dijit code, not if it's your own/production code of course.

Comment: No, that was not Dojo/Dijit code, it was some dojo-based application written by a colleague. I will let him know his code is redundant, thank you very much for the confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

You are right i a way, but not entirely

```
define("my.widget", [ "dojo/_base/declare",.... ], function(declare, ...){
    return declare("my.widget", [ .. ], {
        value : "myvalue"
    });
});
```

here we define module which defines class, so class declaration(constructor) is cached when module is required, meaning class is defined only once. But that doesn't mean you can use it as static, because that's only class declaration, not the instance.

this will not work:

```
require(["my.widget"], function(widget) {
    console.log(widget.value);
});
```

Here is correct usage:

```
require(["my.widget"], function(widget) {
    console.log(new widget().value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think your answer somehow confirms my assumption. The widget example you provide does not show any "module singleton" behavior, and the usage example that will not work is simply because it is the wrong way of using a class, and is totally unrelated with the AMD loader.

Comment: In your example singleton is no way related to AMD. As singleton only ensures that class has one instance, where AMD ensures that class is defined only once and module is loaded once.

Comment: My point is, AMD provides a way to define singletons in a simpler way than without it: since modules are executed only once, there is no need to add checking code. That is how my original question was related to AMD. Notice that AMD can be used to define objects, not only classes.